# If define a function as $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt.$ What is the formula for $F(x)$ on an interval?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function

$$f(t)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if }0\le t<1\\
2 & \text{ if }1\le t\le2
\end{cases}.
$$
We define the function

$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt.$

Find the formula for $F(x)$ on the interval $[0,2]$.

I have to consider two cases

The first case where  $0\le x<1$ and $1\le x\le2$.

Then suppose $0\le x<1$ then I know that $f(t)=1$ and similarly if  $1\le x\le2$ I know that $f(t)=2$. Then wouldn't that mean that $F(x)=1(1)$ for the first case and $F(x)=2(2)=4$ for the second case or am I misunderstanding how to find the formula? Would the graph of $F(x)$ look like another step function?

Comment: You have to integrate. For example, for $x$ from $(0,1)$ You have $F(x)=\int_0^x 1dt=x$.

Comment: $F$ is continuous. Use the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: Oh so then I would have a line $x$ for the first case and a line $2x$ for the second case?

Answer (score 1):

If $0 \le x < 1$,

$$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\, dt=\int_0^x 1\, dt = x$$

If $1 \le x < 2$,

$$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\, dt=\int_0^1 1\, dt + \int_1^x 2 \, dt$$

Try to simplify the second term.